# Vetor de Map em Java

Tags: java, array, estrutura-de-dados, map

Estou com um trabalho de estrutura de dados no qual preciso criar um vetor e implementar a interface `Map` do Java e, dentro dela, eu armazeno os maps ordenados. Já criei o vetor, mas agora não sei como implementar o método `put` (e outros).

```
package vetor;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import estudante.Estudante;

public class Vetor_map implements Map<Object, Object> {


private int nElementos;
private Map mapa[];

public Vetor_map(int max) {
    nElementos = 0;
}

// PUT
@Override
public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        mapa[nElementos].put(key, value);
        nElementos++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (nElementos == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    if (nElementos == mapa.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//tem outros metodos abaixo mas nao implementei ainda
```

Abaixo a `main`:

```
package main;


import estudante.Estudante;
import vetor.Chave;
import vetor.Vetor_map;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    Vetor_map vm = new Vetor_map(10);
    Chave ch = new Chave();
    Estudante es = new Estudante();
    System.out.println("Chave: " + ch + ", Estudante: "+ es);
    
    vm.put(ch, es);
    System.out.println(vm.get(ch));
    
}

}
```

[image: Ao executar retorna NullPointer]

Não acho nenhum exemplo de implementação parecida na internet.

Comment: isso ocorre pq dentro da sua classe Vetor_map a variável mapa não está incializada

Comment: Corrigi essa parte no construtor e segue o mesmo erro, acredito que seja o put, porem nao sei como resolver

Comment: você inicializou os mapas do array também? se você fizer por exemplo Map mapa[] = new Map[10], o array vai estar ok mas os mapas internos ainda assim estarão nulos, você precisa em seguida inicializar o map do index também, por exemplo mapa[0] = new HashMap(); e ai sim dar o put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nao acho nenhum exemplo de implementação parecida na internet

É porque isso não faz sentido algum.

Quero deixar alguns pontos aqui antes de responder:

Isso que você está fazendo(ou que pediram para você fazer) não faz sentido algum, você está implementando a interface *Map* do Java (terá que implementar vários métodos) e está utilizando uma variável para controlar o índice.
Como você fará para obter o valor ao passar determinada chave?
Em cada inserção, você terá que inicializar uma nova estrutura de chave-valor. Sendo assim, cada chave e valor, terá apenas um elemento internamente.

Mas enfim, se é um trabalho de escola, deve ser feito, mas sugiro ler novamente o enunciado e questionar o professor.

Correções que você precisa fazer.

```
public Vetor_map(int max) {
    nElementos = 0;
   // precisa inicializar o vetor
   // estamos alocando a quantidade de bytes necessária para um objeto do tipo hash map * 2
   mapa = new HashMap[2]; // pode ser qualquer tamanho
}


@Override
public Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        // Você inicializou o vetor, mas não inicializou o que tem dentro do vetor
        mapa[nElementos] = new HashMap<>();
        mapa[nElementos].put(key, value);
        // Se precisa ordenar, poderá fazer após a inserção, sugiro o algoritmo INSERTION SORT.
        nElementos++;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários, eu entendo que não faça sentido, e que talvez eu não tenha entendido o enunciado direito, segue o mesmo: Desenvolva uma aplicação para manipular estudantes armazenados em um Mapa,
em que o número de matricula é usado como chave. O TAD mapa é representado pela interface
Map disponível em https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html. Essa
interface deve ser implementada pela dupla ou trio usando três estruturas de dados: Vetor
(ordenado), Lista duplamente encadeada (ordenada) e Árvore Binária.  Como eu poderia interpretar melhor esse anunciado?

Comment: Você precisa implementar uma estrutura de chave valor, e utilizar um vetor, lista encadeada ou árvore binária para tratar as colisões que irão ocorrer.